# JSpinner.DateEditor 5 minute jump

Tags: java, swing, datetime, jspinner

I have a timepicker looking like this:

```
JSpinner timePicker = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());
JSpinner.DateEditor timeEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(timePicker, "HH:mm");
timePicker.setEditor(timeEditor);
timePicker.setValue(new Date());
```

Is it possible to make the minutes only show each 5 minutes instead of every singel minute(i.e. 0,5,10,15,20,25...)?

Comment: Having spent a whole 5 minutes looking around, my personal approach would be to extend `SpinnerDateModel` and override the `getNewValue` method, but there might be a more elegant method...

Comment: I am not sure, if the Pc System will clock do that, because it have to update every minute, even after every second. So you have to use the schedule class, check out this link, it might help you,  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ScheduleExpression.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to have your own SpinnerDateModel and there you have to do changes in setValue() method.
Have a look at [SpinnerDateModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html)